# VLOOKUP issues with full stop

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have this string to match some text using VLOOKUP.

```
=CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP(D10,Clients!A1:F10034,2),", ",VLOOKUP(D10,Clients!A1:F30034,3),", ",VLOOKUP(D10,Clients!A1:F10034,4),", ",VLOOKUP(D10,Clients!A1:F10034,5))
```

When it runs into a match that has a full stop in it, the match returns the first result that matches what it has before the full stop.

Eg if the lookup tries to match "C.B.A Solutions" and there is "C Tyres" & "C.B.A Solutions" inside of "Clients!" it will match "C Tyres" because it comes up first.

Comment: Okay? What are you trying to do? What's the data look like? Can you include another variable to narrow it down? What about `INDEX/MATCH`?

Comment: Better put some sample data and your desired output. Then explain your logic to gain that output so that some can help you to write formula to gain output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your VLOOKUPS are missing the 'optional' forth argument. Note that this forth argument isn't 'optional' **unless** your data is sorted in ascending order and a match is guaranteed (i.e. your lookup term will always exist in the lookup database). Is that the case here? If so, amend your question to clarify. If not, add 'False' in as a forth argument.

Note that your formula is very inefficient. Most of the work that VLOOKUP does is in locating a matching row in the key column where the lookup term is. Better to relegate that computationally expensive task to a dedicated MATCH function in its own column,  and then to feed that result to four INDEX functions.

Put this in a separate column:

```
=MATCH(D10,Clients!A1:F10034,0)
```

Then point some INDEX functions at the answer, instead of using computationally expensive VLOOKUP functions:

```
=CONCATENATE(INDEX(Clients!C1:C30034,[Match Output]),", ",INDEX(Clients!D1:D30034,[Match Output]),,", ",INDEX(Clients!E1:E30034,[Match Output]),)
```

Replace [Match Output] with the cell containing the output of the MATCH function.

Google INDEX and MATCH vs VLOOKUP for why this matters.

Note that sorting your lookup lists and then ommittig that forth argument and using something called the Double VLOOKUP trick (that handles missing values in your lookup list) will be many thousands of times faster again. See my post at the following link for more:
http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2015/04/23/how-much-faster-is-the-double-vlookup-trick/

Comment: I've added more info to my answer showing how you can make things many times faster again by sorting lookup lists and using something called the Double VLOOKUP trick.